# Google Maps Api v3 geocode address, how to return the object

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to return the latitude and longitude of an address via google api v3 geocoding function. The geocoding works fine I just cant set the results to my geocode obj to return from the function. I suspect it is a scope issue

```
function codeAddress(address) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  //this is the container var which I will reurn
  var geocode={};

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        geocode.success = true;
        geocode.position= results[0].geometry.location;
  //If I log geocode here I can see the position and success values in the object
  } else {
      geocode.success=false;
      geocode.message="Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status;

  }
});

  //If I log geocode here it's empty

  return geocode; 
}
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous. You can't "return" anything from it's callback routine, you need to use the data inside the callback function when/where it is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely a scope issue. The callback function you pass to the geocode request is preformed asynchronously.

> Accessing the Geocoding service is asynchronous, since the Google Maps
>   API needs to make a call to an external server. For that reason, you
>   need to pass a callback method to execute upon completion of the
>   request. This callback method processes the result(s).

[Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests)

This means your `codeAddress` function will always return an empty object.

Comment: cheers, passed a callback to the function and all is good :-)